# Pulling encoding UTF-8 in map_df function

Tags: r, utf-8

Could you please try to help me. I want this with support of encoding UTF-8

`full_data <- dir("path", full.names = T) %>% map_df(read.xlsx, sheetIndex = 2)`  it doesnt support UTF-8 encoding and it is crucial for me

Couldn't pull of encoding = "UTF-8" in map_df(), when I try to expand read.xlsx which supports encoding parameter

`full_data <- dir("path", full.names = T) %>% map_df(read.xlsx(encoding = "UTF-8",sheetIndex = 2))`

R claim I didn't provide the "file" argument, which is kind of true, but I don't know how to provide file here, as I am on my way to create file

Lets say I have
One file where the records are

```
    ID      Name      Post Code
    111     Cąóął     000-00
    222     Carlos    111-00
    333     Benito    222-00
```

Second file

```
 ID      Name   Post Code
112     Juan     000-00
221     Javier   111-00
```

Full file

```
     ID      Name      Post Code
    111     Cąóął      000-00    #SPECIAL CHARACTERS AVAILABLE
    222     Carlos     111-00
    333     Benito     222-00
    112     Juan       000-00
    221     Javier     111-00
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're going to achieve, but probably `map_df(~ read.xlsx(file=., encoding="UTF-8", sheet_index=2))`?

Comment: That was it. I finally created full table with UTF. So what does "~" and "file=." do? It gives artificial parameters to the function so one can skip these in fact?

Comment: `~ read.xlsx(file=., encoding="UTF-8", sheet_index=2)` is same with `function(x){ read.xlsx(file=x, encoding="UTF-8", sheet_index=2)}`. Please check the documentation of `purrr::map` function for detail.